# Prove or Disprove $∀a, b ∈ Z,$ if $36a = 28b,$ then $7|a.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove or Disprove $∀a, b ∈ Z,$ if $36a = 28b,$ then $7|a.$

The simplest thing coming to mind is supposing $a$ and $b$ $= 0$. But I probably can't do that.

LCM of 36 and 28 is 252, 28 dividing into any common multiples + 2 times compared to 36.

If I factor it out to receive $9a = 7b$ which should always hold for any integer a,b that satisfies the equality.

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: If $9a=7b$ then $7$ divides $7b$ and thus $9a.$ But $7$ is a prime and $7$ doesn't divide $9$. So?

Comment: Do you know *Gauß' lemma*?

Comment: @99 Fishing:You should edit your question and change ''$\forall a,b \in \mathbb Z$'' $\longrightarrow$ ''for some $a,b \in \mathbb Z$'' as not all $a,b$ satisfy the equation.

Comment: @user438576 One should read it like this for every $a, b$ such that $36a=28b$ we must have that $7\mid a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
36a &=28b\\
\implies b &=\frac{36a}{28}\\
\implies b &=\frac{9a}{7}\\
\end{align}

Since prime $7$ does not divide $9$, $7$ divides $a$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (unique prime decomposition). Two other notes:

- $9$ divides $b$ by similar arguments
- The equation tells us nothing about whether $4$ divides either $a$ or $b$, despite $4$ dividing both $36a$ and $28b$

Comment: The conclusion doesn't actually require the full FTA. It only requires that primes satisfy the ring-theoretic definition of "prime": that if $p \mid rs$ then $p \mid r$ or $p \mid s$. (Then let $p=7, r=9, b=a$.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), every number has one and only one prime factorization. We know if we factor $28b$, we will get $7$ as a prime factor. This means we also need a $7$ in $36a$. Since $36$ is not divisible by $7$, the $7$ will have to come from the $a$. Therefore, $7|a$.

Comment: So because 36 is not divisible by 7 we can assume that the divisibility must come from the a when multiplying by constants a, b that hold an equality? I'm just fuzzy on how this cements my understanding of the proof.Thank you for the response. :)

Comment: $36a$ and $28b$ are the exact same number, just different ways to write it. The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic says that same numbers have one prime factoring. From $28b$, we know that this one prime factoring includes a $7$. Because $36a$ has the same prime factoring, it also has a $7$. However, $7$ does not divide $36$, so the $7$ must be from $a$. In other words, $7|a$.

Answer (score 0):

According to $Gauss's  theorem$ :$a,b,c$ three integers. If $a$ divides $bc$, and $a$  is relatively prime with $b$, so $a$ divides $c$.
 $36a =28b$ so by factorizatin $9a=7b$, $7$ divides $7b$ so $7$ divides $9a$, $7$ is relatively prime with  $9$, so $7$ divides $a$.